# Informatica Target table is not loading data as expected

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a source query which picks data on a daily basis and the mapping is fairly simple which directly inserts data into target. We are however not able to see some users getting inserted into the table. I tried to check if the records are being fetched in Source Query and they are being fetched as expected, But when the scheduled job run is happening the records are not getting loaded into the table.
However, when I run the workflow manually, I can see the data flowing. Please help me in identifying the issue.

Note :- The records which are not getting loaded, are not rejected records as well.
The behavior is erratic, I can see records getting loaded into the target but not all records.

Since the mapping is fairly simple, I have made session properties of commit interval at 10000, Treat source rows as insert.
Even Introduced an Update strategy with DD_INSERT before the table. Its working when we run it manually.
But if it is triggered via a scheduler, We are seeing the data drop.
I'm currently re-migrating all the objects to the environment from an Admin id guessing there might be some privilege issues on the objects when run via a scheduler ( ENSONO )

Comment: If you turn the logging level up, what do you see? Are any records being dropped between the source and target? What selection criteria, if any, do you have for the source? Is the source the actual source for the data (e.g. a database table) or an intermediate source (e.g. a file of new/updated records being generated from a source)?

Comment: Is there any Pre- or Post-SQL query there that could mess the data up?